# Display alert msg in web page when forwarding from one page to another on page load

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect

I have created a html page in php and upon submission i validates that page using PHP. After validating i want to show an alert msg to show its status like showing any greeting or request for re-enter.

I have dont validation. Now i m using

```
header( 'Location: http://localhost/assignment/WebForm.htm' ) ;
```

to redirect user to same page but with a alert msg at page load or something like that. What I need to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `header`, you can't output anything in the document's body, making any `alert()`ing impossible.

A often used trick to achieve this is to delegate the `alert()` ing to the target page:

```
header( 'Location: http://localhost/assignment/WebForm.htm?alert='.
        urlencode("Hello!")) ;
```

and then in WebForm.htm:

```
 <?php if (isset($_GET["alert"])): ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 alert("<?php echo htmlentities(urldecode($_GET["alert"])); ?>");
 </script>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

just remember to `htmlentities()` the output when outputting the message.

If you are already using sessions, for 100% security and elegant URLs,  you could also generate a random key in PHP using `rand`, store the message in `$_SESSION["message_$randomKey"]` and pass the key in the GET request. That way, the only thing the user sees in the URL is the key, and not the message.

Comment: @Pekka Please put some torch on htmlentities also. I m unaware of this

Comment: @Shantanu it's to prevent people from injecting HTML through the GET variable. htmlentities() turns any characters that could "break out" of the alert (e.g. a quote `"`) into their HTML entities (`&quot;`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the alert using Javascript in the other page.

You'll probably want to pass the alert text in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the global variable *$_SESSION* for this -

```
- Use Session to store message
- Redirect user
- Fetch Session value & display it
- unset the Session
```